# Most efficient query to update data between 2 tables - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to update a table with values from another table based on a field. i.e.: sku.

The schema is similar to wordpress.

```
/*
MySQL - 10.5.16-MariaDB : Database - dbtest
*********************************************************************
*/

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=''*/;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`dbtest` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */;

USE `dbtest`;

/*Table structure for table `1_products` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `1_products`;

CREATE TABLE `1_products` (
  `meta_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `1_products` */

insert  into `1_products`(`meta_id`,`post_id`,`meta_key`,`meta_value`) values 
(1,'10','_stock_status','instock'),
(2,'10','_sku','E-CR2025M'),
(4,'20','_stock_status','outofstock'),
(5,'20','_sku','E-SR626SW'),
(7,'30','_stock_status','outofstock'),
(8,'30','_sku','E-SR521SW');

/*Table structure for table `1_sync` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `1_sync`;

CREATE TABLE `1_sync` (
  `sku` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `availability` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `1_sync` */

insert  into `1_sync`(`sku`,`availability`) values 
('E-CR2025M','instock'),
('E-SR626SW','instock'),
('E-SR521SW','instock');

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

I want from table 1_sync that looks like this:

| sku | availability |
| --- | --- |
| E-CR2025M | instock |
| E-SR626SW | instock |
| E-SR521SW | instock |

to update 1_products table's stock_status that matches 1_sync sku:

| meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | _stock_status | instock |
| 2 | 10 | _sku | E-CR2025M |
| 4 | 20 | _stock_status | outofstock |
| 5 | 20 | _sku | E-SR626SW |
| 7 | 30 | _stock_status | outofstock |
| 8 | 30 | _sku | E-SR521SW |

What is the most efficient query to do that so that table 1_products, the rows with _stock_status have the same values of the table 1_sync based on the skus that match the post_id value.

The method i use is:

```
UPDATE `1_products` AS d1,
(
SELECT a1.post_id AS pid, a2.availability AS avl FROM `1_products` AS a1
INNER JOIN `1_sync` AS a2
ON a1.meta_value = a2.sku
) AS upd
SET d1.meta_value = upd.avl
WHERE d1.post_id = upd.pid
AND d1.meta_key = '_stock_status';
```

Comment: Show us the method you have used, then we can tell you if its the most efficient, or provide a better version if its not. Without seeing your current attempt it's impossible to tell if you have done it right

Comment: 1_products will better represent the data if the 'sku' and 'stock status' will be stored in different columns.
It will also be much easier to sync the tables if those two data items are stored in different columns (a simple SELECT ... INTO ... query will do it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)

Comment: @SShahar The schema is like wordpress so can not do that, to store sku and stock status to different columns.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i updated the question with the method i use.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you cannot change the schema (the stock status for each product entity is represented by two rows in 1_products), your solution is the most efficient possible.
Any other variation will have similar performance and effects on table locking/deadlocks.